# graphicx using placeholder image with \graphicspath

Tags: graphics

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{example-image.png}

\end{document}
```

The above successfully compiles, however the output PDF contains a placeholder image instead of the actual `example-image.png`.

It works fine (displaying the expected image) if the above code is changed to remove the `\graphicspath{{./figs/}}` line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{figs/example-image.png}

\end{document}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imho you can prevent that kpathsea looks for the images in the texmf tree if you add `./` to the path. For me (on windows) it works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{./example-image.png}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause while gathering more information to put into the question.

The problem in fact lies in the image name `example-image.png`.

When using `\graphicspath`, the first `example-image.png` that's found is actually one somewhere in the LaTeX directories, which you can see in the compile log:

```
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.png>
```

Thus if you must use `example-image.png` as your image name, you'll have to specify its directory explicitly to avoid the above image from being used.

Alternatively you can change the name of the image to avoid this strange problem.

EDIT: See accepted answer for better solution.